# Links in my hamburger menu detach themselves from navbar while scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm having this issue where I have a navbar and a hamburger menu which displays some links on click.

The links are fixed positioned, and body is set to `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y: scroll`,  but when I try to scroll down the page in mobile, it doesn't work; whereas the whole thing scrolls down too if I remove the `overflow-x` attribute.

I just need to find the way to make the page scroll when the menu is closed and to not do it and not detach from the navbar while it's open. I had to set the `overflow-x: hidden` because in mobile it scrolled to the right where the nav-links were hidden.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');


  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.3s ease-in forwards ${index/7+.5}s`;
      }
    });
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}
navSlide();
```

```css
.nav-up {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background-color: #f4f8ff;
}

.brand {
  color: #740000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Gilda Display", serif;
  color: black;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .nav-links {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 90vh;
    top: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #f4f8ff;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}
.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .logo {
    margin: 1rem;
  }

  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
#hero {
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero {
  background: green;
  height: 80vh;
}

.title {
  font-family: "Gilda Display", serif;
  color: #ede8e6;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: title-effect 2s ease-in forwards;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes title-effect {
  from {
    top: -2rem;
  }
  to {
    top: 7rem;
  }
}
.btn-ver {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Gilda Display", serif;
  background: rgba(161, 175, 179, 0.76);
  border: 1px solid #909ea2;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  animation: btn-effect 2s ease-in forwards;
}
.btn-ver:hover {
  background: rgba(183, 201, 206, 0.76);
}

@keyframes btn-effect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#second-section {
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-up">
  <div class="logo">
    <p class="brand">Hello, world</p>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="">ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TWO</a></li>
    <li><a href="">THREE</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="hide">FOUR</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="hide">FIVE</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="hide">SIX</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="hide">SEVEN</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="hero" id="hero">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <button class="btn-ver" id="verBtn">BUTTON</button>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section2" id="second-section">
  <div class="wrapper-2">
    <div class="title-2">
      <h3 id="sf-t">TITLE TWO</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="par" id="parag">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, litora nunc dignissim massa ornare vitae et vel, netus aptent dictumst class magna at. Nulla dictumst aliquam nostra est suspendisse massa condimentum cubilia ac mauris mi, montes in aenean
        accumsan tempus scelerisque arcu eget eleifend id. Curabitur non gravida iaculis eu vehicula ac mauris porttitor, vivamus feugiat nec laoreet egestas pretium mus, diam sagittis elementum orci accumsan ad venenatis.Varius vel parturient magnis
        nibh mus rutrum odio volutpat quisque curae, egestas dictumst conubia lectus primis himenaeos sagittis hendrerit felis, urna euismod aliquet bibendum facilisis nec ut aliquam luctus. Tincidunt magna ullamcorper odio conubia accumsan massa proin
        eleifend malesuada leo ante, primis platea nascetur laoreet rutrum suscipit pretium potenti sodales class blandit, nostra elementum posuere augue condimentum dictum fringilla auctor sapien eros. Class sodales vehicula mattis eros odio lectus ultrices
        augue magnis imperdiet, primis sollicitudin litora rutrum lacinia lobortis tempor sociosqu.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  Change the nav-links position from fixed to absolute.

```
  .nav-links {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 90vh;
    top: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #f4f8ff;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/nmkzo04x/

Comment: Yes, that works on Firefox but on Chrome you can still scroll to the right and see the overflow that's supposed to be hidden. I can't seem to figure it out and it's kinda driving me crazy. Thanks for taking the time to help anyway!

Comment: In the fiddle I gave I was able to remove to overflows and it seems to work fine for me.  And I am using chrome.  Can you give a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Yes, this is how it looks like with Chrome developer tools. [link](https://res.cloudinary.com/stefii1806/image/upload/v1588996539/Chrome_rw1mdq.jpg)